# Generate traffic between ims and a router for VOIP service TCL script

Tags: tcl

how can i configure a router that supports many simultanous sessions of voip to communicate with ims using TCL?
and how represent three proxies servers of ims in one node ?

Comment: Does ims refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Multimedia_Subsystem ? (I don't know the answer to your question, and just the jargon was confusing to me…)

Comment: yes ims refer to IP Multimedi Subsystem